# Does `reflog` maintain historical record of branch names being created, moved, manipulated, merged, or deleted?

Tags: git

From *Version Control with Git*

> Git does not maintain any form of historical record of branch names being created,
>   moved, manipulated, merged, or deleted. Once a branch name has been removed, it is
>   gone.

A branch name is a ref, so doesn't `reflog`   maintain historical record of branch names being created,
moved, manipulated, merged, or deleted?

Comment: The reflog might maintain a reference to the commits in a now deleted branch, but that does not mean that it stores the time such a branch was created, moved, deleted, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HEAD` reflog can contain entries for branch names that no longer exist (though merely as text, e.g., `moving from asdf to master`).

As Git is constructed today, the reflog for some reference *X* is deleted when *X* itself is deleted.  When *X* is renamed, the reflog is renamed in the same way, without adding any new entry.  This is because the name of the reflog *is* the name of the branch, with `logs/` inserted at the front: the reflog for `master` (`refs/heads/master`) is named `logs/refs/heads/master`, while the reflog for `HEAD` is named `logs/HEAD`.

There exist, in the proposed updates for some future Git, some not-quite-fully-realized code that keeps the reflog around after deleting the reference itself.  So someday, this might change.

Answer (score 2):

Git maintains entries in the branch's reflog if a branch is created, moved, or modified, and in the HEAD reflog if it is checked out. However, Git does not maintain reflog entries for deleted branches, and does not update the reflog of a branch that is merged into another, although it does update the reflog of the branch into which the merge occurred.

Reflog entries are periodically pruned, so the record is not permanent.

Essentially, if a ref is locally created, moved, or modified in some way, that ref's reflog will contain a record of it until the ref is deleted or the entry is pruned.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the limitations torek mentions, the reflog is a local data structure.  That means that *even if* reflogs for deleted branches were kept around, you still would not have a complete log of branch creations, deletions, etc.  The reflogs would only know about branches that had a history on your local clone, and would only know the local history of those branches.